# I cant understand what is [] notation in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to Java, I know what is `List` and `ArrayList` in Java.  If we want to use array we have to determine the size of it.  For example:

```
int[] Course = new int[10];
```

and in array list we have to write it different for example:

```
ArrayList<int> Course = new ArrayList<>();
```

but in this code which dose not have any error we have:

```
private Course[] CourseAr;
```

Wwhat is this?  It is not Array because it does not have size, and it's not ArrayList because it has been written different

```
public class Student {

  private int maxCourse;
  private int registeredCourse=0;
  private Course[] CourseAr;

  public Student(int maxCourse){
    this.maxCourse = maxCourse;
    CourseAr = new Course[maxCourse];
  }
```

Comment: is is an array, what do you think the line `CourseAr=newCourse[maxCourse];` does?

Comment: `private Course[] CourseAr;` is a `Course[]` (so an array) that points to `null` (uninitialized)

Comment: if it is an array why it dose not have size?

Comment: `maxCourse` is the size you gave it to the constructor of Student then actually created the array

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  but maxCourse changes, and I raed the size of an array dose not change

Comment: well the array size won't change after you call `new Course[maxCourse];`.

Comment: no body understand what is it! Course is the name of another class, if I change it it dose not work

Answer (score 3):

> private Course[] CourseAr;

That is a declaration of an array.  The size is required when the array is initialized, but not at declaration time.  It is set in your example below when the array is initialized at:

> CourseAr = new Course[maxCourse];

Best practice in Java is to use a lowercase character as the first charcater of the identifier, so consider naming it `courseAr` or `courses` rather than `CourseAr` which is commonly used in Java to identify classes.

Comment: thanks, could you please give me a source or youtube video that I can study  and learn it?

Comment: Nothing better than the Java Language Specification - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2 - please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: according to the page that you already sent it to me, we have to determine if array is int , object or whatever, but in this code there is nothing?

Comment: Of course there is.  In the declaration `private Course[] CourseAr;` the object type is `Course`.

Comment: But Course is not a object in this class

Comment: Actually  Course is the name of another class

Answer (score 0):

When  you implement the class Student, it has only one constructor, in wich you have to set a value. That value will be the number of courses.

Student student = new Student(2);

That student will have to courses